# How to retrieve installed printers on macOS in C#

Tags: c#, printing, .net-core

I'm writing a console application, and one of the things that application needs to do is retrieve a list of all of the user's installed printers (as well as their paper sources). We can obtain this information easily via System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters on Windows, but accessing the same property on macOS returns seems to be returning an empty list.

We are using .NET Core v2.2 for this application.

The code we're using is just as follows:

```cs
foreach (string pName in PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters) {
  // this should iterate each of the installed printers
}
```

On Windows, it iterates each printer as expected. On Mac, however, it does nothing.

Does the InstalledPrinters property not work on macOS, or is it possible that there's something else preventing it from working correctly? And if it doesn't work, is there any other way to retrieve a list?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, I had the same problem. adding the `System.Drawing.Common` namespace did the trick. Then the namespace could be resolved. And my list is filled with available printers.

Comment: Gave it a try, but still no luck on my side unfortunately.

Comment: I even had to install mono-ligdiplus via homebrew; `brew install mono-libgdiplus` But in some way, the printer receives the print but prints only squares. It looks like the encoding is not correct. But got paper coming out the printer. When running the same console application on a Windows machine, everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug in .NET Core to me.

What version of .NET Core are you using?

.NET Core 2.1 (and later) has code that implements finding the InstalledPrinters on macOS/Linux here: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Drawing.Common/src/System/Drawing/Printing/PrintingServices.Unix.cs

So it should work (unless there's a bug somewhere).

Comment: We've tried both v2.1 and v2.2 with no luck, however no errors being emitted implies CUPS is at least working. One thing we noticed is that ``lpinfo -m`` on the terminal does not seem to output a PPD corresponding to the printer, which may be why it can't be found? Other applications are still able to successfully print to it, though. Would it matter if it was installed via an IP address?

Answer (score 0):

Lpinfo (CUPS) workaround:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("lpstat", "-p")
                {
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    CreateNoWindow         = true
                };
var process   = Process.Start(startInfo);
var output = await process.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
var printerNames = output.Split("\n", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                         .Select(line => line.Split(" ")[1])
                         .Where(name => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
                         .ToArray();
await process.WaitForExitAsync();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n",printerNames));
```